# Connection TimeOut in flutter when making a request to django Rest api locally

Tags: django, flutter, dart, django-rest-framework, flutter-android

void reg() async {
try{
http.Response response = await http.get(Uri.parse("http://10.0.2.2/api/alluser"));
print(response.body);
}
catch(e){
print(e);
}
}

It is working when I am doing in chrome( web) http://127.0.0.1:8000  but not working in android emulator.

in Django's setting.py

ALLOWED_HOST = [10.0.2.2 , 127.0.0.1]

Answer (score 1):

NOTE - Specific for connecting Android and django rest api in Flutter

I tried lot of things but connection timeout was occuring. I was using django Rest-Api

1. go to Command Prompt type ipconfig copy ipv4 address in my case 192.168.2.4.
   [image]

2. add 192.168.2.4 in ALLOWED_HOST =[] in django settings.py.
3. type "python manage.py runserver 192.168.2.4:8000" to run your server.
   4)In Flutter
   your baseurl for accesing django rest api should be "http://192.168.2.4:8000/"

This worked for me . thanks